# Why is my React's component click method triggered at rendering time?

Tags: reactjs

I am rewriting ReactJS's ["starter game"](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR?editors=0010%20)) in ES6 with arrow functions (to remove the use of `.bind()`, class properties and typescript.

Apparently in my code `handleSquareClick` is triggered at rendering time, `setState` is hence executed, resulting in  error

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

**Why**?

**Game.tsx**:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import Board from "../Board";

class Game extends PureComponent {

    state = {

        history: [{
            squares: Array(9).fill(null)
        }],

        currentStep: 0,

        xIsNext: true
    };


    handleSquareClick = (i) => {
        console.log(i);

        // ...more code here

        this.setState({
           history: [...historyClone, { squares }],
           currentStep: historyClone.length,
           xIsNext: !xIsNext
        });

    };


    render() {
        const { history, currentStep } = this.state;

        const current = history[currentStep];

        return (
            <div>
                {  }
                <Board
                    squares={current.squares}
                    handleSquareClick={this.handleSquareClick}

            <
        );
    }

}

export default Game;
```

**Board.tsx**

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {
    Title,
    Square
} from './styles';

class Board extends PureComponent {

    getSquareStringValue(value) {
        if (value === 0) return 'X';
        else if (value === 1) return 'O';
        else return '';
    }

    renderSquare(props) {
        const { key, value } = props;

        return (
            <Square
                    key={key}
                    className="square"
                    onClick={this.props.handleSquareClick(value)}>
                { this.getSquareStringValue(value) }
            </Square>
        )
    }

    render() {
        const { title, squares } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="board">
                <Title>{title}</Title>
                <div>
                    {[...Array(3).keys()]
                        .map((i) => (
                            <div className="board-row" key={i}>
                                {[...Array(3).keys()]
                                    .map((j) => this.renderSquare({
                                        key: (i+1)*(j+1),
                                        value: squares[i]
                                    }))
                                }
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        title: "Board",
    };
}



export default Board;
```

**Board/styles.ts**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Title = styled.h1`
    font-size: 1rem;
`;


export const Square = styled.div`
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
`;
```

Comment: Can you please share the source code of board.tsx? As you have shared the same code in both snippets

Comment: @AliHayder fixed

Comment: Part of the answer right now is "you tell us?" You have plenty of code left to reduce: strip out all the functions that don't contribute to the problem, so that what's left is the most compact demonstration of this still happening. But usually in the process of forming that [mcve], you actually discover the problem all on your own and it turns into a "I guess I should just delete this question" situation

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I simplified the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change this:

```
onClick={this.props.handleSquareClick(value)}>
```

to this:

```
onClick={()=> this.props.handleSquareClick(value)}>
```

because `onClick` expects a function as a value, but what you were doing is that you were calling this function.

We know that if we put () at the end of a function, that function is called. So what I changed is to pass the function without calling it, by using a `() => ...` arrow function.

Comment: Thanks @Ali. seems to work. can you explain why specifically?

Comment: This is because onClick expects a function as a value but what you were doing is that you were calling this function like this `this.props.handleSquareClick(value)`. We know that if we put `() `at the end of a function, that function is called. So what I made change is to pass function without calling it which is `()=> ` this arrow function is definition of function but it is not calling at the same moment instead it is definition of the function which has another function inside it being called which is `this.props.handleSquareClick(value)`